# How do enable cut, copy in JPasswordField?

Tags: java, swing, jpasswordfield

I noticed that i was unable to cut and copy in `JPasswordField`? Now how to copy/cut the selected part of the password to clipboard? Are there any methods to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple, use this method

```
JPasswordField jt=new JPasswordField(20);

            // Put client property
            jt.putClientProperty("JPasswordField.cutCopyAllowed",true);

            add(jt);
```

By default, the password in the `JPasswordField` is not allowed to be cut/copied. All you need to do is to enable them.

As per the comment on disabling paste i didn't find a property, but i have achieved using this, (i dont recommend this way)

```
jt.getActionMap().put("a",null);
        jt.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl V"),"a");
```

Another way, is to do override the `paste()` (i recommend this way) while declaring

```
JPasswordField jt=new JPasswordField(20){
  public void paste(){}
};
```

**Update:** I misunderstood the comment. But the above does disabling paste. However to disable any one of the copy/cut/paste, it is better if the required method that is to be disabled is overrided with no implementation in it.

If there is a much better way, i would love to hear.

Comment: @nachokk ["it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is _explicitly_ encouraged"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: Interesting. Is there a way to allow pasting but disable coping content from JPasswordField?

Comment: disagree quite not true up to Java7

Comment: @mKorbel What is not true?

Comment: in Javas6 (already tried before my comment here) I'm able to copy password from MsWord etc..., too lazy to test in Java7