# How to cut/copy text in JPasswordField as char array?

Tags: java, swing, jpasswordfield

How to cut/copy the password in the `JPasswordField` into the clipboard by using the **non-String API**. Thereby closing a window for the hacker to see the password.

According to this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/8885343/2534090 the char array is different from the text.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object pw = "Password";
    System.out.println("String: " + pw);

    pw = "Password".toCharArray();
    System.out.println("Array: " + pw);
}
```

**Prints:**

```
String: Password
Array: [C@5829428e
```

What i want to be in the clipboard is `[C@5829428e` but not `Password`

I tried using `StringSelection` to copy the contents in the clipboard but it's constructor takes a `String` which is immutable and not safe.

Comment: I am really confused while reading your question. You want to get the char-Array of a JPasswordField and have already found the method for this. What do you exactly want to do with the password?

Comment: this might give you some heads up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706393/how-do-enable-cut-copy-in-jpasswordfield

Comment: See when you print the char array, you get a different output, when you print the getText() you get the text (i.e. the password). Now my question is how to get that different output into clipboard!

Comment: When you print the char array how? The char array contains the password just like the String does.

Comment: @EJP See this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/8885343/2534090

Comment: Are you referring to the fact that char[].toString() doesn't reveal the contents?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom `TransferHandler` to do this.

According to the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using and Creating a Data Flavor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/dataflavor.html) you should be able to use the char[] as the object written to the clipboard.

However, I couldn't get it working and ended up writing a StringBuilder to the clipboard. I commented out the code were I attempted to use the char[], maybe someone else can figure out what I did wrong.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.io.*;

public class PasswordHandler extends TransferHandler
{
//  public final static DataFlavor CHAR_ARRAY_FLAVOR = new DataFlavor(char[].class, "Char Array");
    public final static DataFlavor CHAR_ARRAY_FLAVOR = new DataFlavor(StringBuilder.class, "StringBuilder");

    @Override
    public int getSourceActions(JComponent c)
    {
        return COPY;
    }

    @Override
    public Transferable createTransferable(final JComponent c)
    {
        return new Transferable()
        {
            @Override
            public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor)
            {
                JPasswordField textField = (JPasswordField)c;
//              return textField.getPassword();
                return new StringBuilder( textField.getText() );
            }

            @Override
            public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors()
            {
                DataFlavor[] flavors = new DataFlavor[1];
                flavors[0] = CHAR_ARRAY_FLAVOR;
                return flavors;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor)
            {
                return flavor.equals(CHAR_ARRAY_FLAVOR);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canImport(TransferSupport support)
    {
        boolean canImport = support.isDataFlavorSupported(CHAR_ARRAY_FLAVOR);
        return canImport;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean importData(TransferSupport support)
    {
//      char[] password;
        StringBuilder password;

        try
        {
//          password = (char[])support.getTransferable().getTransferData(CHAR_ARRAY_FLAVOR);
            password = (StringBuilder)support.getTransferable().getTransferData(CHAR_ARRAY_FLAVOR);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        JPasswordField textField = (JPasswordField)support.getComponent();
        textField.setText(password.toString());
        return true;
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JPasswordField tf1 = new JPasswordField(10);
        JPasswordField tf2 = new JPasswordField(10);

        TransferHandler handler = new PasswordHandler();
        tf1.setTransferHandler( handler );
        tf2.setTransferHandler( handler );
        tf1.putClientProperty("JPasswordField.cutCopyAllowed",true);
        tf2.putClientProperty("JPasswordField.cutCopyAllowed",true);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Password Copy");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(tf1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(tf2, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(new JTextField(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The code takes the entire text from the password field. If you only want the selected characters then you will need to modify the `getTransferData()` method to only add the selected characters to the StringBuilder.